# Switching backlight brightness to zero by pressing fn-key

Tags: shortcut-keys, brightness, backlight

I have Ubuntu 16.04LTS running on my Dell XPS 15 9550. Until yesterday the fn-key for setting the brightness was able to set the brightness level to 0 (shutting backlight off completely) which I absoluetly appreciated while starting a movie on an external display. After the firmware update yesterday this feature is gone :(.

I searched the internet for a while and found the possibility to switching the backlight off by entering the command:

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightnes
```

This actually does exactly what I want. But if I set the brightness to the lowest level by pressing fn-key it stops at 1.

I can see that by the command

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

Is there a way to change the minimum brightness level to zero by pressing the fn-key?

-- Edit --

According to the post [Can I adjust the minimum brightness for my laptop's LCD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689040/can-i-adjust-the-minimum-brightness-for-my-laptops-lcd)
 there is a way of setting this over the fn-keys. But the script

> /etc/acpi/asus-keyboard-backlight.sh

is never called (Following the tutorial https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaptopSpecialKeys).

acpi_listen gives me

> video/brightnessdown BRTDN 00000087 00000000

But I was not able to figure out which script is actually triggered by the event (so far).